# Angular 4 Nested Routes failing with named route-outlet

Tags: angular

I have a named router-outlet for a multi-paged form in an Angular 4 app.

My routes look like the follow:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: CompA },
{ path: 'routeB', component: CompB },
{ path: 'routeC', component: CompC, children: [ 
  { path: '', component: subCompA, outlet: 'ruleManagerOutlet'},      
  { path: 'subrouteB', component: subCompB, outlet: 'ruleManagerOutlet' },
  { path: 'subrouteC', component: subCompC, outlet: 'ruleManagerOutlet'}
 ]},
{ path: 'healthcheck', component: HealthCheckComponent }
];
```

Besides that my html looks like the following:

```
<div class="content-area">
    <router-outlet name="ruleManagerOutlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

when I try and hit the routeC/subrouteB I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL 
Segment: 'routeC/subrouteB'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'newIntent/segmentation'
at ApplyRedirects.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.es5.js:1466)
```

I'm not sure exactly what I'm missing. Thanks in advance!

Edit: To make this more clear, I have a component that is rendered in the main router-outlet. Within this component, I would like to render multiple sub-components in order to implement a multi-paged form.

Comment: Do you have a primary router-outlet within `CompC` alongside your named router-outlet?

Comment: No, the primary router-outlet is not alongside the named router-outlet. The named router-outlet is inside the primary router-outlet.

Comment: does it work when you remove the named router-outlet? The error makes me think the routes aren't being used properly since it looks like it should be able to match `routeC/subrouteB`, do your other routes work `routeB` ,`routeC`